# send email from model and template

Tags: php, symfony1, model, symfony-1.4

if i want send email with SwiftMailer in symfony then i must in action:

```
$message = $this->getMailer()->compose(
      array('user@gmail.com' => 'user'),
      $affiliate->getEmail(),
      'Jobeet affiliate token',
      body
    );

    $this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

but this doesnt working in template and in model (i would like create function for this).

Comment: Please understand that as symfony implements MVC, you ar enot supposed to send emails from neither template nor model. If you want to do this, there may be some ways (e.g. making the mailer avaiable in your template), but it will get ugly!

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? what errors do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend sending mail using a template - put a link in the template and call the action to send the mail ... you can send from a model although again i wouldn't recommend it as using `sfContext::getInstance()` inside the model is a really bad practice as it makes the model class rely on the context. So, your model class can't be unit tested as it needs a context to work...

You need an instance of the current sfContext to do it ... i would suggest passing it as a parameter when you create the model

Comment: Realy realy not recommended to send email within template!